# Azure Function app in Mac exits with exit code 137

Tags: azure, macos, azure-functions

I am trying to get the default Python Azure Function app to work locally. I simply want to make sure it works and I can do a hello world for now.

I have an ARM CPU mac, so I've enabled Rosetta so my terminal emulates x86_64 as per this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=macos%2Cazurecli%2Cv2%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-python#enable-rosetta-in-terminal

I then proceed to install the Azure function core tools: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=macos%2Cazurecli%2Cv2%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-python#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools

I create the default HTTP Triggered Function app with Python. I run `func start` and it seems to work fora few seconds then I get this error:

```
 Language Worker Process exited. Pid=51054.
 python3 exited with code 137 (0x89). .
 Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: python.
 System.Private.CoreLib: A task was canceled.
 Language Worker Process exited. Pid=51061.
 python3 exited with code 137 (0x89). .
```

What am I doing wrong ? It

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` ,`host.json` and `local.settings.json` file.